# How to configure Nginx and Varnish with Magento

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, nginx, ssl, varnish

Recently we decided to go ahead and install varnish for use with Magento, along with Nginx for SSL termination.

Apache is serving to port 8080, Varnish is on port 80, and Nginx is configured to handle the SSL traffic on port 443.

The problem I'm encountering is with Nginx, when attempting to start the process we get the error `Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with an error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

After running `systemctl status nginx.service` we get the following:

```
● nginx.service - A high-performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-01-04 12:26:38 MST; 27s ago
  Process: 6732 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6729 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 04 12:26:35 s132-148-86-33.secureserver.net nginx[6732]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:443, backlog 511 failed (98: Address alrea
Jan 04 12:26:36 s132-148-86-33.secureserver.net nginx[6732]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:8080, backlog 511 failed (98: Address alre
Jan 04 12:26:36 s132-148-86-33.secureserver.net nginx[6732]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:443, backlog 511 failed (98: Address alrea
Jan 04 12:26:36 s132-148-86-33.secureserver.net nginx[6732]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:8080, backlog 511 failed (98: Address alre
Jan 04 12:26:36 s132-148-86-33.secureserver.net nginx[6732]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:443, backlog 511 failed (98: Address alrea
Jan 04 12:26:37 s132-148-86-33.secureserver.net nginx[6732]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:8080, backlog 511 failed (98: Address alre
Jan 04 12:26:37 s132-148-86-33.secureserver.net nginx[6732]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:443, backlog 511 failed (98: Address alrea
Jan 04 12:26:37 s132-148-86-33.secureserver.net nginx[6732]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:8080, backlog 511 failed (98: Address alre
Jan 04 12:26:37 s132-148-86-33.secureserver.net nginx[6732]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:443, backlog 511 failed (98: Address alrea
Jan 04 12:26:38 s132-148-86-33.secureserver.net nginx[6732]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

And from there, I'm kind of lost as this is my first go around with either Varnish or Nginx. Anybody else ran into a similar issue or have any suggestions on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this error was being caused because within our `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file, there was still a setting for SSL pointing to 443. Changed it and Nginx seems to be working fine now.

Comment: instead of 443 what should I need to change?